# Oxidation of 1,4,5,8-tetrahydronaphthalene by meta-chloroperoxybenzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I came across this question in Himanshu Pandey. I can't understand why the m-CPBA attacks the central pi bond and not the lateral ones. The answer given is C.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As the following figure indicates, the terminal oxygen in a peracid (the oxygen involved in the epoxidation) has a partial positive charge ; therefore **this oxygen is electrophilic**.

[image: peracid epoxidation]

([image source](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch06/ch6-9.html))

The central double bond in your compound is tetrasubsituted, the lateral bonds are only disubstituted with alkyl substituents (remember that alkyl groups are electron donating).  Consequently **the central double bond is the most electron rich** and will be the preferred site of attack for the electrophilic oxygen.

Comment: But why arent we giving hyperconjugation a priority here,in that case the middle bond is more stable

Comment: @DIPANJANChowdhury  While hypercojugation is important it is usually outweighed by the effect of a substituent directly attached to the carbon in question.